# Poweroff issue in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - its restarting everytime

Tags: power-management, shutdown, restart

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my machine, but come up with a very strange issue, every time I am clicking on the Poweroff button, instead of shutting it down, it just restarting the machine.

I tried to find some forums on this but didn't get any firm answer on this.

Please help me with this, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify for me. You are saying when you go to the top right and choose shut down and then in the pop up shut down again it restarts? OR are you talking about the physical power button on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying when you press power button your computer restarts right ?
Try :
Go to the settings app
Then open power options
There scroll down and you'll  see
Suspended & Power Button
There in power button behaviour select power off
it should work By the way you should shutdown by clicking on top right menu > Power Off /Log Out > Power off

Answer (score 0):

If other answers fail, you can try the following command.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```